# Loading .eml files into javax.mail.Messages

Tags: unit-testing, email, mocking, mockito, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to unit test a method which processes `javax.mail.Message` instances.

I am writing a converter to change emails which arrive in different formats and are then converted into a consistent internal format (`MyMessage`).  This conversion will usually depend on the from-address or reply-address of the email, and the parts of the email, the subject, and the from- and reply-addresses will be required for creating the new `MyMessage`.

I have a collection of raw emails which are saved locally as `.eml` files, and I'd like to make a unit test which loads the `.eml` files from the classpath and converts them to `javax.mail.Message` instances.  Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem came from using Mockito to mock the `javax.mail.Folder` required by `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`'s constructor `MimeMessage(Folder, InputStream, int)`.  This calls the constructor for `javax.mail.Message` `Message(Folder, int)` which then accesses `folder.store.session`.  This resulted in a `NullPointerException` being thrown by the constructor for `MimeMessage`.

Solution:

```
class ClasspathMimeMessage extends MimeMessage {
    private ClasspathMimeMessage(Folder folder, InputStream is, int msgnum) throws MessagingException {
        super(folder, is, 0);
    }

    public static MimeMessage create(String resourceName) {
        Class<PopEmailMmsReceiverTest> loaderClass = PopEmailMmsReceiverTest.class;
        InputStream is = loaderClass.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);

        Folder inbox = new MyFolder();

        try {
            return new ClasspathMimeMessage(inbox, is, 0);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load email from classpath at " + loaderClass.getResource(resourceName).toString());
        }
    }
}

class MyFolder extends Folder {
    MyFolder() {
        super(createMockStore());
    }
    private static Store createMockStore() {
        return mock(Store.class);
    }
    public void appendMessages(Message[] msgs) throws MessagingException {
    }
    public void close(boolean expunge) throws MessagingException {
    }
    public boolean create(int type) throws MessagingException {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean delete(boolean recurse) throws MessagingException {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean exists() throws MessagingException {
        return false;
    }
    public Message[] expunge() throws MessagingException {
        return null;
    }
    public Folder getFolder(String name) throws MessagingException {
        return null;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return null;
    }
    public Message getMessage(int msgnum) throws MessagingException {
        return null;
    }
    public int getMessageCount() throws MessagingException {
        return 0;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }
    public Folder getParent() throws MessagingException {
        return null;
    }
    public Flags getPermanentFlags() {
        return null;
    }
    public char getSeparator() throws MessagingException {
        return 0;
    }
    public int getType() throws MessagingException {
        return 0;
    }
    public boolean hasNewMessages() throws MessagingException {
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return false;
    }
    public Folder[] list(String pattern) throws MessagingException {
        return null;
    }
    public void open(int mode) throws MessagingException {
    }
    public boolean renameTo(Folder f) throws MessagingException {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

This looks very ugly to me, so if anyone has a better suggestion, I'd be delighted to hear it.

Answer (score 13):

After a few tests, I finally successfully loaded a message using the `MimeMessage(Session, InputStream)` public constructor (as opposed to the Folder-based protected one cited in the other response).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class LoadEML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(null, is);
        System.out.println("Subject: " + mime.getSubject());
    }

}
```