# Display .eml file in a web appication

Tags: java, html, email, viewer

I have a web application where I need to display .eml files (in RFC 822 format) to the users, formatted properly as e-mail - show the HTML to text body properly, show images, attachments and so on. Do you know of a component / library that can do those things?

I prefer it would be in Java (and to integrate with spring easily :-) ), but any other implementation which runs on Apache is fine as well.

Comment: Would .NET components running with mod_mono be OK?

Comment: @Oded - what do you have in mind?

Comment: There are a number of proprietary .NET libraries/solutions that may be able to run under mono/apache. This is more of a long shot as it will need to be tested. If there is something native, I would go with that.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz So... Did you ever find anything?

Comment: It's been a long time since i have needed that, but I haven't find anything. I guess it's such a corner use case in practice, so there's no component for that. Also, the web UI is not trends to JS mostly code(Node, Angular, React, etc.), less Java based sites, so I don't think there will be one.

Answer (score 0):

Javamail can read EML file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class ReadEmail {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
       display(new File("C:\\temp\\message.eml"));

   }

   public static void display(File emlFile) throws Exception{
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", "smtp.dummydomain.com");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        InputStream source = new FileInputStream(emlFile);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);


        System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("Body : " +  message.getContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't take care of embedded images, attachments, multipart messages and other issues. I was hoping to avoid all these.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert .eml into javax.mail.Messages mailMessage as:

[Loading .eml files into javax.mail.Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781739/loading-eml-files-into-javax-mail-messages)

then you could use this library to convert in MessageBean:

http://javaclue.blogspot.com/2009/09/portable-java-mail-message-bean_02.html

MessageBean mb = MessageBeanUtil.mimeToBean(mailMessage);

Comment: And how is it going to display my e-mail as web-page?

Comment: There are several frameworks for displaying server-side processing. For example, you could use Spring MVC. Here is an example:
https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/