# how to get inner subject from .eml file in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I have an email file in which one mail is attached. Under this mail two attachment are there, One is text file and other is email. I want all subject part which is present in .eml file. I am working on java platform please help me to find the subject part from .eml file.

Comment: This question has a solution here: [Loading .eml files into javax.mail.Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781739/loading-eml-files-into-javax-mail-messages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading .eml files into javax.mail.Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781739/loading-eml-files-into-javax-mail-messages)

Comment: @jon sampson  sir in above link, i didn't get solution of my question. It only give the solution to load the .eml to MimeMessage, not getting the inner subject of .eml file.

Comment: @AshishRanjan The third line of the main method in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649955/6768037) is literally what you asked for.

Comment: @JonSampson sir if mail doesn't contain any attachment of mail then i get the subject from .eml file but, if mail contains another mail and that mail contains two attachment one is text file another is email. I want to access inner mail subject from .eml file.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a multipart message or nested email. I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846572/reading-eml-file-using-javamail-api-to-parse-sender-subject-massege-etc) question and answer. Therein you would find a link to the [JavaMail msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples). Note the dumpPart(Part p) method especially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading .eml file using Javamail API to parse sender,subject massege etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846572/reading-eml-file-using-javamail-api-to-parse-sender-subject-massege-etc)

Comment: @JonSampson thanks sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaMail sample program [msgshow.java](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) shows you how, in general, to traverse the structure of a message and examine all of its parts.  Point it at your sample message and you'll see what it does.

For your use case, the key is to understand that the nested message will be a part of type message/rfc822, and the getContent method on that part will return an object of type MimeMessage.  Once you have that MimeMessage object, you can use the getSubject method or any other method to access that data in that nested message.